# Can Android app links work with an app installed under app profile?

Tags: android, deep-linking

My application uses magic link sign in. It is handle by our app via Android app link (verified deep link). The app link doesn't get triggered to open the app if the app was installed under work profile. It works fine when the app was installed under personal profile. The apks in both cases are signed with the same release key.

Is there just an innate limitation in Android that app links don't work with work profile? Do I have to fallback to regular deep links instead?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can share things across profiles, when using deep links, they are not recognized by a browser in a different profile. Which is the whole point of the profiles, that apps cannot detect anything outside of their profile.